# What characteristics would a 12-string guitar without the double strings have compared to conventional 6-strings guitars?

Tags: acoustic-guitar

If you remove a the octave strings on a 12 string acoustic how would the guitar then compare to conventional 6-string, acoustic guitars? 12 strings have bigger bodies, would they then be analogous to some of the bigger body acoustics, like a Taylor Grand Orchestra for instance?

Comment: There are plenty of 12-string guitars which have the same body size as their 6-string stable-mates. It's usually the heads that are longer, to accommodate the extra machine heads. there will be little difference - there wasn't in those I used many years ago - I would check when changing strings, after putting only the basic set on.

Comment: Well, for one thing, you'd have less tension on the neck, so you'd have to adjust the truss. Not sure if changing the tension by this much is actually a good idea, though.

Answer (score 1):

The neck of a 12 string is wider than a regular acoustic, so people with particularly large hands might like that.

The overall build is often also a little thicker and sturdier, to withstand the extra tension, and therefore the overall resonance of the guitar will be a little less.

But having said that, I think that the difference between one brand and another, or the difference between cheaper and better models is going to be far greater than the difference between 6-string and 12-string versions of the same model.